# Locating sent emails from Outlook with atteched items in OneDrive

Tags: email, onedrive

I have just sent an email with some files which are located on OneDrive. Where would I locate "sent items"?

Comment: In your Outlook.com account's "Sent Items" folder?

Answer (score 2):

When you attach files from your OneDrive to an email it will still show up in the sent items folder of your mail client / outlook.com.

Comment: Are you referring to having Outlook.com as your email server on a cell phone?

Comment: It doesn't matter which email provider you use.